# Is there any way to get request data in django serializer?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

This is the sample view where I am taking some query_params and I want to access the same in serializer which will I use in this view accordingly.

```
class SomeApi(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        username = request.query_params.get('username')
        page = request.query_params.get('page')
        phone = request.query_params.get('phone')
        if username and page and phone:
            return Response({'message':'some message'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({'message':'error'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is a sample Serializer where I want to get query_param phone if available and write some logic to return an extra method field.

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Some
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_isPhone(self, obj):
        phone = ??? #HERE I WANT TO GET phone query_params which is passed in API call
        if phone:
            return phone
        else:
            return 0
```

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context

Comment: can you please explain it with the same example as used in the question?

Comment: I tried to implement the same but it is raising key error

Comment: What key error? Can you add what you have tried to your question?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem right, you should create the serializer with incoming data , and then try `is_valid()` method on your serializer, there is specific hooks when using `is_valid()` that you can access your data before validation, in your case I think you should use `to_internal_value()`

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    # here is the first place to manipulate data you can do what ever you want with 
    #your data          
    return super().to_internal_value(data)
```